# How-to fix .NET 5.0 to 6.0 migration error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-standard-2.1

I have a NetStandard2.1 library that is used for data access in a WebApi I was going to upgrade the WebApi and the data access to .NET 6.0.

dotnet --info shows the following .NET SDKs installed

```
NET SDKs installed:
 3.1.415 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk
 5.0.403 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk
 6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk
 6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk
 6.0.100 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk
```

There are only 3 packages within the data  access class library.

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore  (5.0.10)
2. Microsoft.EntityframeworkCore  (5.0.10)
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer  (5.0.10)

But when I try to upgrade the packages to 6.0.0 I am receiving a Nuget error of NU1202 for all three packages. Example of errors is:

Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.0 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

Could the two 6.0.0-previews be causing an issue?
Can someone please help with the upgrade issue?
I must be missing something that I should be changing or doing!
Thanks...

Orgbrat

Comment: There is no .NET Standard version compatible with .NET 6. If you need .NET 6 functionality from within your library, your library has to be .NET 6 too. (Of course, you can still use a .NET Standard library in .NET 6, as long as it only uses .NET Standard functionality.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Plan for Entity Framework Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/plan):

> EF Core 6.0 requires .NET 6. EF Core 6.0 does not target any .NET Standard version; for more information see [the future of .NET Standard](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/).

You'll need to upgrade your library to target `net6.0` in order to use Entity Framework 6:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

This also means that projects consuming this library will need to target .NET 6.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and moving all projects to net6.0 was the answer. Again thanks you folks saved me some headaches.